# What is NoOpMediator in Clean Architecture

Tags: clean-architecture, mediatr, ardalis-cleanarchitecture

I am playing around with the [Clean Architecture by Ardalis](https://ardalis.com/clean-architecture-asp-net-core/).

Can someone please explain what this [NoOpMediator](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/tests/Clean.Architecture.UnitTests/NoOpMediator.cs) role in Unit testing?

```cs
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using MediatR;

namespace Clean.Architecture.UnitTests;

public class NoOpMediator : IMediator
{
  public Task Publish(object notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
  {
    return Task.CompletedTask;
  }

  ...
  ...
}
```

It does not seem to do anything. For [four of its methods it returns Task.CompletedTask](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/af7379fedcef0176f3f1dfc0dc41bf047c3843db/tests/Clean.Architecture.UnitTests/NoOpMediator.cs#L10). And for the [rest of the two it returns Task.FromResult<object?>(default)](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/af7379fedcef0176f3f1dfc0dc41bf047c3843db/tests/Clean.Architecture.UnitTests/NoOpMediator.cs#L20)

Further more in the [BaseEfRepoTestFixture class here](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/af7379fedcef0176f3f1dfc0dc41bf047c3843db/tests/Clean.Architecture.IntegrationTests/Data/BaseEfRepoTestFixture.cs#L17), there is no configuration of Mock object. Bit misty.

Also noted that this is configured in [CustomWebApplicationFactory](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/tests/Clean.Architecture.FunctionalTests/CustomWebApplicationFactory.cs) way [down here](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/af7379fedcef0176f3f1dfc0dc41bf047c3843db/tests/Clean.Architecture.FunctionalTests/CustomWebApplicationFactory.cs#L87).

```
services.AddScoped<IMediator, NoOpMediator>();
```

Even if I comment out that line, the tests still pass.

[image: Units tests sill passing even after NoOpMediator Configuration is removed]

There should be an example test to show how this works.

Comment: Just a guess: As `NoOpMediator` returns `IMediator` you could use https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/472f0f8e213b2bd466da025c5fea05be1a13f5b8/tests/Clean.Architecture.IntegrationTests/Data/BaseEfRepoTestFixture.cs for mocking. At least there is shown how it's mocked: `var mockMediator = new Mock<IMediator>();`

Comment: I'm not convinced that the sense of `NoOpMediator` is this, but perhaps it helps somehow: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern . Perhaps you should ask in the repository about the sense of the class.

Comment: I went to [this clean arch repo issues](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/issues/new/choose) and clicked question. And that got me here. Any way I will try to create a test with mockMediator as you suggested.